# How do I escape the escape character in Emmet?

Tags: escaping, code-snippets, emmet

I am trying to make a custom shortcut in Emmmet because I am using MathJax. I have tried using \ to escape the escape character, to no avail. Below is my emmet code that does not yet work. I'm trying to get the '\' to print out in my shortcut.

```
Preferences -> Package Settings -> Emmet > User Settings

"snippets": {
      "css": {
         "snippets": {
            "mza": "margin: 0 auto;"
         }
      },
      "html": {
         "snippets": {
            "frac": "\\frac{}{}",
            "lfrt": "\\left( \\right)"
         }
      }  
   }
```

Actual results are:

frac{}{}

and

left( right)

Answer (score 0):

:-) Just figured it out.

\\\\ will print one '\' character.

jcpartri